# MYSQL Error : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me why i keep getting an error with this sql query ?

```
            select hour , price , date
            from
            (
                select Hour(c_date) as hour , avg_price AS price , c_date as date
                from brc_table
                where c_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 Week)
            )
            group by date
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  But a table alias after the `)`.  However, the query still doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to do?  Having an aggregation query with unaggregated columns doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must assing  a name to the derived  table,   your form ( select ....  )
 so add  eg :   t ad the endo of from()

```
       select hour , price , date
        from
        (
            select Hour(c_date) as hour , avg_price AS price , c_date as date
            from brc_table
            where c_date >= date_sub(now(), interval 1 Week)
        ) t 
        group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, `DATE` is a "Reserved Word", so you cannot have a column named `date`, and you cannot use the word `date` in an alias (as with `AS date`.)

You should either pick some name other than 'date', or you should quote the word 'date' with back-quotes, (otherwise known as backticks,) like this:

```
`date`
```